# Angular HighChart Update

Tags: angular, highcharts

When dynamically plot options are changed, the highchart is not redrawing itself.

I have used highcharts in my code like.

In HTML:
`<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options" [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"></highcharts-chart>`

In TS:

```
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = function (chart): void {
    chart.redraw();
};

  chartOptions: Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "line",
        data: this.inputdata
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to update the highcharts with dynamically changing input data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `update` property and set it to true when you want to update the chart.

```
  <highcharts-chart 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    >
  </highcharts-chart>
```

---

```
export class AppComponent  {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFlag = false;

  data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [
      {
        data: this.data
      }
    ]
  }

  handleUpdate() {    
    this.chartOptions.series[0] = {
      data: this.data.reverse()
    }

    this.updateFlag = true;
  }
}
```

---

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details