# How to update highcharts series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to update the series date for highcharts in angular application. But it is not working. How to update it?

```
 updateSeries(){
  let arr = [ 
    {
      name: 'Corn',
      data: [12, 135, 80],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      data: [8, 49, 81],
    }, 
  ]; 
  this.chartOptions.series = arr;

  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-k6pezt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi, the following thread should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971831/angular-highchart-update

Comment: @magdalena: Not able to update like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-hegfzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is the type error, so you can fix that by assigning to the matching one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-dnnvzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts